# Java Reactive. How to wait for all data in flux and then process them

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm getting data from mongo reactive repository and updating it. Then I have to collect all data in one collection and path it to another service to get more info. Then I should map them in one Flux. My code is:

```
        Flux<Views> views = someRepository.findAllByUsersIn(userId).doOnNext(v -> {
        v.setInterlocutor(v.getUsers().stream().filter(u -> !userId.equals(u)).findFirst().orElse(null));
    });
    

    return Flux.zip(views.map(view -> conversionService.convert(view, ResponseViewDto.class)), getUserInfo(views).flux())
            .flatMap(fZip -> {
                ResponseViewDto dto = fZip.getT1();
                dto.setInterlocutor(fZip.getT2().get(dto.getInter()));
                return Flux.just(dto);
            });
```

**getUserInfo** does collecting usersId and sends them to another service and returns expanded info.

I found that getting from DB calls 2 times and I can understand why, but is there any solution to do it once and still be not blocking.

Comment: Can't you use [collectList()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#collectList--)?

Comment: @MichaelBerry yeah, I can and then work with a list of objects. It's one of the options. But this solution is in an imperative way. I just think about doing it by flux/mono stack in a declarative way

Comment: You got 2 db calls because you subscribe to `views` twice when zipping. Try to [`cache()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#cache--) after db call to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `Adhika Setya Pramudita` for help. The way to do what I need  is just to use `cache()` method